# PHP mPDF QR-Code with special characters like LF and CR

Tags: php, qr-code, mpdf

We have to implement a system called "Zahlen mit Code" (German for "pay by code"), a convenient, fast and lossless way of initiating credit transfers by using your smartphone & a QR-Code.

As mpdf (used by the php-based invoice-system "[invoiceplane](https://invoiceplane.com/)" for exports) can manage the QR-Code generation with flying colors we desperately seek for a solution to our problem: The creation of QR-Codes that contain special characters like Lf and Cr. (We need them to meet the requirements: "Elements are separated with line endings, where both variants Lf and CrLf are permitted.", Reference [it's worth reading]: https://www.stuzza.at/de/download/qr-code/339-qr-code-und-bcd-definition-2-en/file.html, Page 5)

To create a QR-Code within our UTF-8 coded HTML we use code snippets like:

```
<barcode code="Two\rlines" size="0.8" type="QR" error="M" class="barcode" />
```

Unfortunately, using "\r" within the QR-Code-text doesn't do the trick (there is no actual carriage return, only the used characters - e.g. "\r" appear within the string). We tried several variants like `\n`; `&#13;` [HTML dec], `&#xd;` [HTML hex]; `0x0D` (UTF8 hex) and so on. Our guess is that it gets escaped by some sanitizing code or we simply escape it the wrong way (or just use the wrong special/control character).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is only possible with mPDF since version `7.0`. The `\r\n` and `\n` characters in the barcode `code` parameter are treated as actual newlines.

Comment: Thx @Finwe, QR-Codes with \r\n work like charm now. 